# Where's the source code for the Shipping Methods in One Page Checkout?

Tags: onepage-checkout, shipping-methods, onestepcheckout

I know the Shipping Methods are loaded dynamically, but where is the file that they're loaded from? I want to slightly change the layout and add some classes, but I can't find the file.

It's not `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml`

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure that your file render from the path specified or check whether any extension overwrite `available.phtml` file.
- Check whether same file exists in your current theme : `app/design/frontend/[Your-package]/[Your-Theme]/template/checkout/shipping_method/available.phtml`

Comment: Yes, it was an extension that I forgot I installed! And I wasted half a day searching core magento files for an answer haha. Thanks!